# Can I pass URL parameter into a get request in django?

Tags: python, django

I'm passing a slug in the url like this:

```
url(r'^fragen/(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/beantworten/$', qna_answer_add,
    name="qna_answer_add"),
```

Can I use the slug like this:

```
qna_answer_model.question = Question.objects.get(slug=slug)
```

Or will it be a security risk, because it comes from the url? Do I need to do a clean up or a regex check or will Django do that automatically?

Comment: _ is included in the characters referenced by `\w`, so you can remove that

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can use it, django does it for you.

```
def your_view(request,slug):
    //you can use your slug as you want
    qna_answer_model.question = Question.objects.get(slug=slug)
```

Answer (score 1):

A safer alternative might be:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def your_view(request, slug):
    qna_answer_model.question = get_object_or_404(Question, slug=slug)
```

or if you need exacting control over what is done in the case of no Question for a slug:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def your_view(request, slug):
    try:
        qna_answer_model.question = Question.objects.get(slug=slug)
    except Question.DoesNotExist:
        # do something else
```